# How to find out if user interact on view controller?

Tags: ios, view, controller, gestures, interaction

I have a view controller, where I am using a timer to close this view controller. I've got there some buttons, but I need when user use some gesture, I need to reset that timer. So I must handle every gesture in specific view controller and call reset timer function there. I know there is a way to override UIApplication method `(void)sendEvent:` and send some broadcast notification. But I would like to handle it on view controller. Somehow catch all notifications and call method.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

[UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller) is inherited from [UIResponder](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder) class.

So you may choose to implement all of `UIResponder` class' Touch Events from your problem.

From [Docs:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder#symbols)

```
func touchesBegan(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?) // Tells this object that one or more new touches occurred in a view or window.
func touchesMoved(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?) // Tells the responder when one or more touches associated with an event changed.
func touchesEnded(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?) // Tells the responder when one or more fingers are raised from a view or window.
func touchesCancelled(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?) // Tells the responder when a system event (such as a system alert) cancels a touch sequence.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yup my mistake you mention UIResponder :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, problem is I've got some buttons in my view controller, navigation controller embed in, search .. And touchesBegan work just when I tapped on view, where is no button or navigation bar. I need somehow cover whole window.

Comment: For that you can add a transparent view on top of your current view (which is having buttons and other controls within itself) & then you can implement the same delegate methods for that newly added transparent view.

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController has methods like

```
 - touchesBegan(_:with:) 
 - touchesEnded(_:with:)
 - touchesMoved(_:with:)
 - touchesCancelled(_:with:)
```

Will that suffice your needs?

Comment: It's not a method of UIViewController's It's a method of UIView's

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle user interaction/action on view.

**Tap Gesture: By using [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer)**

UITapGestureRecognizer is a concrete subclass of UIGestureRecognizer that looks for single or multiple taps. For the gesture to be recognized, the specified number of fingers must tap the view a specified number of times.

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .Ended {
        // handling code
    }
}
```

**Touch: By using [UITouch](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitouch)** (Inherited from [UIResponder](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder) by UIViewController)

UITouch object represents the location, size, movement, and force of a touch occurring on the screen.

```
func touchesBegan(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?) // Tells this object that one or more new touches occurred in a view or window.
func touchesMoved(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?) // Tells the responder when one or more touches associated with an event changed.
func touchesEnded(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?) // Tells the responder when one or more fingers are raised from a view or window.
func touchesCancelled(Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?) // Tells the responder when a system event (such as a system alert) cancels a touch sequence.
```